# how to make a custom listview selectable and launch a new activity/fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-intent, fragment, android-listfragment

I've made a custom listview and i have it in a `ListFragment`. i'm able to make the rows selectable in my `ListViewAdapter` class. but i would like to make them selectabe from my `CompraFragment` class which extens `ListFragment` and by selecting a row i would like to launch the relative detail page. So i have 2 questions:

1) How do i make my ListFragment class have selectable rows and then launch the detail page though intents or by fragment manager. and here comes in the second question;

2) Should i launch a detail page as a `Fragmet` or `Activity` (considering that i already have a slide menu which lauches `Fragments` and/or `ListFragments`. So basically a 3 level paging system (menu -> items -> item detail))

Here is my code:

fragment_compra.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

my custom listView row: `listview_item_row.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" 
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
    android:padding="5dip" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:background="@drawable/list_selector" >

            <!-- Image dell'ogetto -->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ic_thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="95dip"
        android:layout_height="95dip"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_thumbnail" />

    <!-- Data di scadenza-->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvScadenza"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ic_thumbnail"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ic_thumbnail"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#040404"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:textStyle="italic"/>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/hProgressBar"
        style="@style/CustomProgressBar"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progressbar_color"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvScadenza"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ic_thumbnail"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false" />

    <!-- Prezzo -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvPrezzo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/tvScadenza"
        android:textColor="#343434"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ic_thumbnail" />

    <!-- Followers -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvFollowers"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvPrezzo"
        android:textColor="#343434"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@color/light_grey"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ic_thumbnail"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:text="@string/followers" />

    <!-- Bottone Segui -->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSegui"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_segui_m"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tvFollowers" />


    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

ListViewAdapter class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.prjma.lovertech.R;
import com.prjma.lovertech.model.Item;

public class ListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    public Context context; 
    public int layoutResourceId;
    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> items;
    public Bitmap icon;

    //public ImageLoader imageLoader;

    public ListViewAdapter(Context context, int listviewItemRow, ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> items, Bitmap icon) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        super(context, listviewItemRow);
        this.items = items;
        this.context = context;
        this.icon = icon;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    public Item getItem(Item position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item_row, null);

        HashMap<String, Object> item = items.get(position);

        if (item != null) {

            ImageView listImage = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.ic_thumbnail);
            TextView scadenza = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tvScadenza);
            TextView prezzo = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tvPrezzo);
            TextView followers = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tvFollowers);
            ProgressBar hProgressBar = (ProgressBar)row.findViewById(R.id.hProgressBar);


            if (listImage != null) {
                listImage.setImageBitmap(icon);
                listImage.setImageBitmap((Bitmap) item.get("pic1m"));
            }

            if (scadenza != null) {
                scadenza.setText((CharSequence) item.get("scadenza"));
            }
            if (prezzo != null) {
                prezzo.setText((CharSequence) item.get("prezzo"));
            }
            if (followers != null) {
                followers.setText((CharSequence) item.get("followers"));
            }
            if (hProgressBar != null) {
                hProgressBar.setProgress((Integer) item.get("coefficient"));
            }
        }

        //row.onListItemClick(new OnItemClickListener1());
        row.setOnClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(position));
        return row;
    }

    private class OnItemClickListener implements OnClickListener {

        private int mPosition;

        private OnItemClickListener(int position){
            mPosition = position;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Log.i("onListItemClickList", "Item clicked: " + mPosition);

            Toast.makeText(context, "Message " + Integer.toString(mPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }   
    }
}
```

compraFragment class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.prjma.lovertech.R;
import com.prjma.lovertech.adapter.ListViewAdapter;
import com.prjma.lovertech.util.MVPFunctions;


public class CompraFragment extends ListFragment {


    public ListView listView;
    public ListViewAdapter adapter;

    /**
     * Keep track of the login task to ensure we can cancel it if requested.
     */
    private DownloadTask mDownloadTask = null;

    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> items;
    public Bitmap icon;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_compra, false); 
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_compra, container, false); 

        // now you must initialize your list view
        listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.list); 

        mDownloadTask = new DownloadTask();
        mDownloadTask.execute((Void) null);     

        return rootView;
    }



    /**
     * Represents an asynchronous login/registration task used to authenticate
     * the user.
     */
    public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

        private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO: attempt authentication against a network service.

            //prendi tutti gli id dal webserver
            ArrayList<Long> ids = MVPFunctions.getMioSingolo().search();

            //per ogni id prendi l'elemento con tutti i valuori di risposta
            items = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
            for(int i=0; i < ids.size(); i++){
                items.add(MVPFunctions.getMioSingolo().getItem(ids.get(i)));
            }
            return true;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            /*
             * This is executed on UI thread before doInBackground(). It is
             * the perfect place to show the progress dialog.
             */
            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "Wall", "Downloading Content...");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
            mDownloadTask = null;

            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            //showProgress(false);

            if (items.get(0).get("status error")!= null){
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "status error = " + items.get(0).get("status error"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.i("status error put toast", (String) items.get(0).get("status error"));
                //fai qualcosa, tipo torna indietro, ecc
            }
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            ListViewAdapter adapter = new ListViewAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.listview_item_row, items, icon);
            // updating listview
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            mDownloadTask = null;
            //showProgress(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you can start an activity using intent.

Comment: can u please show me how in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can see the listview with items as expected, then next simplest way to perform item-click is to implement `OnItemClickListener` for the class. Here,

```
public class CompraFragment extends ListFragment implements OnItemClickListener
```

Then add unimplemented method, then do as usual- third parameter will be the clicked item position and switch-ing it, you call your Intent for next Activity.